# sql server lag function where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

In the database, I have +1000,+2000,+3000..... increasing values according to the previous value. These sometimes do not increase, but decrease, I wrote a listing query to find this out.

```
select NUMBER-lag(NUMBER) over (ORDER BY DATE_TIME) AS 'DIFF' 
from exampleTable with(nolock) 
WHERE CONDITION1='abcdef' AND DATE_TIME >='20220801'
```

This works and I export to excel and filter and find the ones less than 0, but should I add them directly to the where part in sql?

I tried HAVING because it is a non-normal field, and it didn't work either.

```
AND (NUMBER-lag(NUMBER) over (ORDER BY DATE_TIME))<0
ORDER BY DATE_TIME ASC
```

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK`? That's not a `go fast` switch, that's a `read dirty or duplicate data while taking more locks and throwing from time to time`. If your query has performance issues fix them, don't try to cover them up

Comment: Mr. Panagiotis They got used to using with(nolock) and said its purpose is to avoid data conflicts. Does this really not work?

Comment: You can't use `LAG` in the `WHERE`. You'll need to use a CTE or derived table.

Comment: Larnu your saying is temp table?

Comment: As for the question itself, it's unclear what you want to do. Analytic functions can only appear in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: *"said its purpose is to avoid data conflicts."* That statement is grossly wrong.

Comment: *"Larnu your saying is temp table?"* No, a CTE (Common Table Expression) or derived table.

Comment: @kadocolak `They got used to using with(nolock) and said its purpose is to avoid data conflicts.` "they" should go to a SQL Server course then, because that's most definitely not what it is for. It *causes* data conflicts.

Comment: @Larnu is saying to use WITH  CTE AS (select NUMBER-lag(NUMBER) over (ORDER BY DATE_TIME) AS 'DIFF' 
from exampleTable with(nolock) 
WHERE CONDITION1='abcdef' AND DATE_TIME >='20220801')

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE DIFF <0

Comment: If you want to use the result of an analytic function like `LAG` for filtering, you must put it in a subquery or CTE and then filter that subquery's (or CTE's) columns. Eg `select ... from (select ,Lag()...... as Diff) as x where x.Diff>0`

Comment: Mr. Panagiotis when I looked with SET STATS IO ON in my own experiments, I didn't see any difference between queries with and without with(nolock), thanks for your explanatory answers.

Comment: Whoever used NOLOCK should read first [Using NOLOCK? Here’s How You’ll Get the Wrong Query Results.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/) and then [NOLOCK Is Bad And You Probably Shouldn’t Use It.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/)

Comment: @kadocolak we aren't talking about statistics. This isn't a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically it is like this,

```
  ;WITH CTE AS (
                    select NUMBER-lag(NUMBER) over (ORDER BY DATE_TIME) AS'DIFF' from exampleTable with(nolock) 
WHERE CONDITION1='abcdef' AND DATE_TIME >='20220801'
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE DIFF <0
```